# Timer doesnt end when it reaches zero

Tags: javascript, timer, intervals, countdown

I have been working on this javascript timer and can't understand why it doesnt stop when the hours, minutes and seconds are equal to zero.

Code:

```
var s= 18000;
var h= Math.floor(s/3600);
s-= h*3600;
var m= Math.floor(s/60);
s -= m*60;
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
{
  if(s == 0 ){
    if(m == 0){
      h=h-1;
      s=59;
      m=59;
      if(h == 0){
        clearInterval(counter);
      }
    } else {
      m=m-1;
      s=59;
    }
    //Do code for showing the number of seconds here
  } else {
    s = s - 1;
  }
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=h+'hrs '+m+'min '+s+'secs ';
}
```

Comment: I think your counter stops one second after there is exactly 1 hour on the counter. (0:59:59)

Comment: It's because you ***a*** subtract 1 from h ***b*** set s to 59 ***c*** set m to 59. If you comment out those three lines and set s to an initial value of 10 rather than 1800, the timer stops after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see here is that you'll decrement `h` variable by 1 when all time variables - and by *time variables* I mean `h`, `m` and `s` are set to zero:

```
if(s == 0 ) {
  if(m == 0) {
      h=h-1;
      s=59;
      m=59;
// more code goes here
```

So `h` will be `-1` and the timer will never stop.
The best I can propose is to rewrite your timer completely, and use only seconds here. Every time the `timer` function gets invoked you check if `s` equals to zero - if it is, you stop the timer. Otherwise, you decrement `s` by 1. To update the inner HTML of `#timer` element you can recalculate the number of hours, minutes and seconds on the every invocation of `timer` method - this solution will be a lot more easier to understand and maintain than the chain of nested conditional statements.

Comment: I get the first part you say. But for displaying the hours, minutes and seconds are you suggesting that I calculate the hours, minutes and seconds every second?

Comment: @crm yes, that's what I'm proposing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the logic in this section here...

```
 if(s == 0 ){
    if(m == 0){
      h=h-1;   // what if h is also 0 here??   this would set it negative
      s=59;
      m=59;
      if(h == 0){
        clearInterval(counter);
      }
```

I think you should be doing your `if(h==0)` check sooner...  before you decrement the values.   So you might want to start your if else block with a `if (s == 0 && m == 00 && h == 0)` and use that to clear the interval.  If everything is already zero, you don't want to change any more values.